# Restart Datalab Kernel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

With my Datalab instance, I can't run my script because the Kernel is dead and i don't have any option to select Python3 or Python 2.

I restarted the session and tried also to restart the VM also, but nothing changed, the Kernel option is still unavalaible to choose!

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/2169) when connecting to Datalab from the Cloud Shell. You can workaround this issue by [connecting to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#top_of_page) without Cloud Shell and create a tunnel on port 8080 to display the Datalab UI on your machine.

In addition, I suggest switching to [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/introduction) which provides an easy to use managed JupyterLab VM similar to Datalab and don't have this issue. [Here's](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new) the quickstart to create a notebook.